# How to query on all model at once Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Can we able to query all model on one query function, I have three separate model community, course, and channel on those there is a name field which similar to all I need to query on all model at once with that name field.

something like

`const names = await allModels.find({name: "Joe"})`

`names` should return documents from community, course, and channel where name is equal to "Joe"

One query function should search on all models.

Comment: [$lookup?](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) [(mongoose docs)](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-lookup)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can easily query all three collections in parallel using `Promise.all`:

```
const allNames = await Promise.all([
    Community.find({name: 'Joe'}),
    Course.find({name: 'Joe'}),
    Channel.find({name: 'Joe'})
]);
```

`allNames` will be an array of three elements, with each element being the results from each collection, in order.